# Print a changing variable in Python Zelle graphics window

Tags: python, window, ipython, zelle-graphics

I have created a window using Zelle graphics in Python and want to print the value of a variable which changes after every iteration. Here is my code:

```
from graphics import *
import random
from time import sleep

def myWindow(dim,Array,win):


    for j in range (dim):
        rec = Rectangle(Point(5+j, 10), Point(6 + j, 11))
        rec.setFill("white")
        rec.draw(win)    
        Array.append(rec)

    label = "Dimension =", dim
    text = Text(Point(10,8), label)
    text.draw(win) 


def main():
    dim = 10
    Array = []
    win = GraphWin("Game of Life", 400, 400)
    win. setCoords(0, 0, 20, 20)

    myWindow(dim,Array,win)


    for i in range (10):
        sleep(1)
        dim = dim - i - 1
        Array[i].setFill("Black")

    sleep(5)    

main()
```

You can see that the array colour changes after every iteration and the dimension (variable `dim` in my code) of the array is being reduced by one unit. Now I want to print the correct dimension in the window.

My code does not change the value of dimension in the graphics window, though the colour changes after each iteration.

Why is the displayed value of the variable `dim` not changing? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `text.setText("...")` to update the content of the label.  I've modified your code accordingly below:

```
from time import sleep
from graphics import *

def myWindow(dim, array, win):

    for j in range(dim):
        rec = Rectangle(Point(5 + j, 10), Point(6 + j, 11))
        rec.setFill("white")
        rec.draw(win)
        array.append(rec)

    label = "Dimension = {}".format(dim)
    text = Text(Point(10, 8), label)
    text.draw(win)

    return text

def main():
    dim = 10
    array = []
    win = GraphWin("Game of Life", 400, 400)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 20, 20)

    text = myWindow(dim, array, win)

    for i in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        dim = dim - i - 1
        array[i].setFill("Black")
        text.setText("Dimension = {}".format(dim))

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

The `dim` variable doesn't behave in your code in the manner you describe in your text but no matter -- it's current value is being displayed and you can adjust it as needed.

Comment: yes you are right, I have to use `dim = dim - 1`. Thanks for your help. But I am facing a new issue. Suppose, I have to print more than one variable. Then what to do? e.g if I want to print `dim` and `(dim - 1)`, how to modify the `label`?

Comment: @ddas, the label is any arbitrary string you want it to be.  Create the string using any of Python's `str` methods and then use `setText("...")` to change the label.  You can also have multiple labels displaying the different text.